# Why is this basic python program not working?

Tags: python, email, text, organization

Well the program is supposed to check if the it sees an "ok" next to the email and if it does spit out the email in another txt file.

Input txt file:

```
.......ng0@gmail.com,ok
.......ad@live.com,fail
.......12@live.com,fail
.......5w@live.com,fail
.......np@gmail.com,ok
.......an@live.com,fail
.......40@excite.com,fail
.......g1@gmail.com,ok
```

python code is:

```
readEmails = open("C:\\Users\\Greg\\Desktop\\rewriteEmails.txt","r")
writeEmails = open("C:\\Users\\Greg\\Desktop\\OutputEmails.txt","w")

for line in readEmails:
    subbed = line[-3:]
    if subbed == "ok":
        split = line.split(",")
        writeEmails.write(split[0])
        print("Email Added")
    else:
        print("Error")
```

The program seems to always go to the else part of the if statement. I'm kinda having a brain fart; i would love your advice.

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging? If it seems to keep hitting the else condition, it means `subbed` is not `==` to "ok", so what is `line[-3:]` returning?

Comment: Lines also contain newline characters at the end.

Comment: If only there some way to **strip** those off...

Comment: If this is an actual csv file then consider using the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), it will take care of the newlines and will split the fields for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line

```
subbed = line[-3:]
```

This returns the following:

```
ok\n
```

or

```
il\n
```

Thus, your `if` statement checking if `subbed == 'ok'` will fail every time.

You can fix this by only taking the last two characters, after stripping the newline:

```
subbed = line.strip()[-2:]
```

---

My original answer didn't account for reading from a file. That answer assumed that the results would be either `,ok` or `ail`. This is not the correct response when reading from a file. The answer above has been modified to show what will be returned and adjusts the solution appropriately.

Comment: `line[-3:]` will actually return `"ok\n"` or `'il\n'`  apart from the last line.

Comment: For last line this may still fail though, it will be better to strip first and then take a slice of 2.

Comment: You are correct @AshwiniChaudhary. I've adjusted where the `strip()` occurs.

Answer (score 5):

This line: `subbed = line[-3:]`  will give you the last 3 chars of `line` which can never be 'ok' which is 2 chars.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of depending on string length (you have 3 instead of 2), you can do this `line.strip().endswith('ok')`

Comment: This makes the intent of the code far clearer. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Simply that the last three characters of an "ok" line are ",ok":

```
>>> line = ".......g1@gmail.com,ok"
>>> line[-3:]
',ok'
```

*edit*
The previous lines end in a new line, so we get the newline character included instead of the comma:

```
>>> line = """.......ng0@gmail.com,ok
... """
>>> line[-3:]
'ok\n'
```

*edit ends*

Perhaps you should just compare the last two characters:

```
for line in readEmails:
    subbed = line[-2:]
    #as you were
```

For a genuine error case, it is often reporting the error, then you can tell what's up easily. Instead of just saying

```
else:
    print("Error")
```

you could print out the `subbed` variable too, and it may have become obvious where the problem lay.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600701/why-is-this-basic-python-program-not-working#comment49270188_30600778

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem with regex. Here is example for your code.

```
import re

for line in readEmails:
    subbed = re.match("(?:.*),(\\w+)", line)
    print(subbed.group(1))
    if subbed.group(1) == "ok":
        writeEmails.write(subbed.group(1))
        print("Email Added")
    else:
        print("Error")
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary
everything is better with regex.
plus, in the future it will be very easy to change ending from "ok" to something else

Comment: Regex is unnecessary for this trivial case, I would go for: `line.rstrip().endswith("ok")`.